# Why do I get a 403 response code if I pass all the parameters using the Exchange Rates API in Java?

Tags: java, api, netbeans

I am currently learning to consume an API in Java, I am using the Exchange Rates API, however, it failed to understand what is happening, I send all the requested parameters and I also send my API key as header.

```
 private static void sendHttpGETRequest(String fromCode, String toCode, double amount) throws IOException, JSONException{
        
        String GET_URL = "https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/convert?to="+toCode+"&from="+fromCode+"&amount="+amount;        

        URL url = new URL(GET_URL);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(200 * 1000);
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(200 * 1000);                
        
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("apikey", "MyApiKeY");
        int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
        
        System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);
                
        if(responseCode == httpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){//SUCESS
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            
            while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                response.append(inputLine);
            }in.close();             
            
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            Double exchangeRate = obj.getJSONObject("rates").getDouble(fromCode);
            System.out.println(obj.getJSONObject("rates"));
            System.out.println(exchangeRate); //keep for debugging
            System.out.println();
            
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("GET request failed");
        }                                          
    }
```

I have used setConnectTimeout and setReadTimeout to set the network timeout thinking that was the problem but still getting the same error.

Comment: HTTP errors are always sent by the target server after they understood your request, so timeouts and other connection level issues can be ruled out. 403 is not documented on https://apilayer.com/marketplace/exchangerates_data-api#errors but I would take something like postman and try the request with api key. There should be a reason given: *"If the response code is not 200, it means the operation failed somehow and you may need to take an action accordingly. You can check the response (which will be in JSON format) for a field called 'message' that briefly explains the error reported."*

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue while using Spring Web's RestTemplate to try and make the API call.

APILayer is using OKHttpClient (from the `okhttp3` library) for their demo samples.
This fixed it for me.

Here is what this could look like for you:

```
import java.io.*;
import okhttp3.*;

public class main {
  public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url("https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/convert?to=to&from=from&amount=amount")
      .addHeader("apikey", "MyApiKeY")
      .method("GET", })
      .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response.body().string());
  }
}
```